# Audio controls in lock screen iPhone, iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, avfoundation

I use AVFoundation to play audio. When i lock my device with playing music, and press Home button twice, I can see audio controls: forward, rewind, pause/play and volume slider
[image]

How to use them? When i press they don't do anything. Onlu volume slider works good.

Comment: For the other poor souls seeing this as top Google result, go here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384965/is-it-possible-to-add-track-title-to-now-playing-controls-menu-as-music-app-or