# Is it possible to add track title to "Now Playing Controls" menu as Music app or ITunesU do?

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, avaudiosession

I'm, creating a player app. I've implemented 'remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:' method and could change playing state by this buttons ([apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/RemoteControl/RemoteControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH7-SW1)). But when something playing from 'Music' or 'iTunes U' apps, than there are a song title appear under remote controls.

[image: song title from music app]

Is there any way to show there my own text from my player app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's done through the [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: thanks a lot! =) Also I found this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600592/change-lock-screen-background-audio-controls-text Meybe it will help somebody)